# Prevent Replay protection in Preauthorized functions

Tags: contract-design, gas

I was looking for a way to send transaction on behalf of users in Dapp. Luckily, I came across the [EIP 662](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/662).

I am implementing something suggested [here by emansipater](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/662#issuecomment-312933815)

As stated in EIP, the replay protection can be done using mappings:

```
mapping(bytes32 => bool) played;
mapping(address => nonce) nonce;
```

I am not sure why both played and nonce are required to prevent replay protection, I think, only `nonce` will do the job.

Since nonce will be different each time a transaction is signed by user and hence no once can resend same signed data.

So what is need for **played** ?

Answer (score 1):

You are citing question, but look at the [answer](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/662#issuecomment-312955124). There is no `nonce` in the answer, only `played`. Either `played` or `nonce` by itself is enough to protect from reply attack, but `nonce` will also protect from out of order execution, that's why I personally would prefer `nonce` over `played`.  Though some people would say that out of order execution is a feature rather than a vulnerability, so they would prefer `played` over `nonce`.

Comment: Yeah great. I also prefer nonce over played. I saw another article here https://espeoblockchain.com/blog/ethereum-gas-price/, they are using both nonce and played. Just wanted to be sure, I am not vulnerable if I use nonce only and get rid of played